Deserialize Token Account in Rust Client
I am trying to obtain the state of a token account(spl_token::state::Account::AccountState), How do I deserialize a raw Solana Account to obtain this state. Other solutions i have come across involve using AccountInfo but I want to achieve this with rust without using anchor

AccountInfo is not an Anchor type, but rather a solana-program type. So if you want to get the state, you can deserialize from a given AccountInfo using:
solana_program::entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Create an iterator to safely reference accounts in the slice
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let token_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let token_account = Account::unpack(&token_account_info.try_borrow_data()?)?;
    let state = token_account.state;
}

Adapted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/1044fe47f7bf005b64c11a8a867b911ae13ae442/examples/rust/transfer-tokens/src/processor.rs#L44
